# Batch DB2 Performance of COMMIT/ROLLBACK VS ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe

In a COBOL batch program what is better in performance terms?

With commit:

```
IF SW-NEW-TRANSACT
  EXEC SQL
      COMMIT
  END-EXEC
END-IF.
PERFORM SOMETHING
   THRU SOMETHING-EXIT.
IF SW-ERROR
  EXEC SQL
      ROLLBACK
  END-EXEC
END-IF.
```

With syncpoints:

```
IF SW-NEW-TRANSACT
  EXEC SQL
      SAVEPOINT NAMEPOINT ON ROLLBACK RETAIN CURSORS
  END-EXEC
END-IF.
PERFORM SOMETHING
   THRU SOMETHING-EXIT.
IF SW-ERROR
  EXEC SQL
      ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT NAMEPOINT
  END-EXEC
END-IF.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SAVEPOINTs and COMMITs are not interchangeable.

A process always has to COMMIT or ROLLBACK database work at some point. A COMMIT is
taken **between** transactions (between complete units of work). COMMIT may be taken after each transaction or, as is common in batch processing, 
after some multiple number of transactions. A COMMIT should
never be taken mid-transaction (this defeats the UNIT OF WORK concept).

A SAVEPOINT is generally taken and possibly released **within** a single unit of work. SAVEPOINTs should always be released upon completion of
a unit of work. They are always released upon a COMMIT.

The purpose
of a SAVEPOINT is to allow partial backout from within a unit of work. This is useful when a process begins with a sequence of common
database inserts/updates followed by a process branch where some updates may be performed before it can be determined that the alternate process
branch should have been executed. The SAVEPOINT allows backing out of the "blind alley" branch and then continuing on with the alternate
branch while preserving the common "up front" work. Without a SAVEPOINT, backing out of a "blind alley" might have required extensive data
buffering within the transaction (complex processing) or a ROLLBACK and re-do from the start of the transaction with some sort of flag
indicating that the alternative process branch needs to be followed. All this leads to complex application logic. 
ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT has several advantages.
It can preserve "up front" work, saving the cost of doing it over. It saves rolling back the entire transaction. Rollbacks can be more
"expensive" than the original inserts/updates were and may span multiple transactions (depending on the commit frequency). 
Finally, process complexity is generally reduced when database work can be
selectively "undone" through a ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT.

How might SAVEPOINT be used to improve the efficiency of your batch program? If your transactions employ self induced rollbacks to recover
from "blind alley" processing, then SAVEPOINT can be a huge benefit. Similarly, if the internal processing logic is complicated by the
need to avoid performing database updates for similar "backout" requirements, then SAVEPOINT can be used to refactor the process into
something that is quite a bit simpler and probably more efficient. Outside of these factors, SAVEPOINT is not going to affect performance
in a positive manner.

Some claim that having a high COMMIT frequency in a batch program reduces performance. Consequently, the lower the commit frequency
the better the performance. Tuning COMMIT frequency is not trivial. The lower the commit frequency, the longer database resources are
held and consequently, the greater the probability of inducing database timeouts. Suffering a database timeout generally causes
a process to rollback. The rollback is a **very expensive operation**. ROLLBACKs are a big hit to the DBMS itself and
your transaction needs to re-apply all of the updates a second time once it is restarted. Lowering commit frequency can end up
costing you a lot more than it gains. BEWARE!

**EDIT**

Rule of thumb: Commits have a cost. Rollbacks have a higher cost.

Discounting rollbacks
due to bad data, device failure and program abends (all of which should be rare), most rollbacks are caused by
timeout due to resource contention among processes. Doing fewer commits increases db contention. Doing
fewer commits may improve performance. The trick
is to find where performance gained in not committing out weights the cost of rollbacks due to contention. There
are a large number of factors that influence this - may of them dynamic. My overall advice is to look elsewhere
to improve performance - tuning commit frequency (where timeouts are not the issue) is generally a low return
investment.

Other more fruitful ways to improve batch preformance often involve:

- improving paralleslism by load splitting and running multiple images of the same job
- analyzing db/2 bind plans and optomizing access paths
- profiling the behaviour of the batch programs and refactoring those parts consuming the most resources

Comment: So, it's a specific decision for each case and there isn't a general guide line, right?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a performance issue at all.

You COMMIT when you finish a unit of work, whatever a unit of work means to your application.  Usually, it means that you've processed a complete transaction.  In the batch world, you'd take a commit after 1,000 to 2,000 transactions, so you don't spend all your time COMMITing.  The number depends on how many transactions you can rerun in the event of a ROLLBACK.

You ROLLBACK when you've encountered an error of some sort, either a database error or an application error.

You [SAVEPOINT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.apsg/qsvpt.htm) when you are processing a complex unit of work, and you want to save what you've done without taking a full COMMIT.  In other words, you would take one or more SAVEPOINTs and then finally take a COMMIT.

Comment: For your answer it seems to me that COMMIT is more costly than SAVEPOINT, is this right?
If so, do you have any documentation on that?
I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the CPU load of a batch that performs complex operations and executes COMMITs on every 500 operations but should rollback only for operation on error.

Comment: A SAVEPOINT is a partial COMMIT.  On a ROLLBACK, you roll back to the last commit, not the last save point.  You can roll back to the last save point, but that's a special ROLLBACK command, not a general roll back.  I would try increasing your COMMIT count to 2,000 and see if that decreases the processing time enough.  It will not impact CPU utilization.

Comment: Why would not impact CPU utilization?

Comment: Because data base processing is I/O bound, not CPU bound.

Comment: It's from an [old source](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/c0007027.htm) (DB2 UDB v8, which has long been out of service), but there is a little bit of information on performance in that article:  `Savepoints give you better performance and a cleaner application design than using multiple COMMIT and ROLLBACK statements. When you issue a COMMIT statement, DB2 must do some extra work to commit the current transaction and start a new transaction.`  There is a little more info on that page, so I would recommend you take a look.

Comment: Thanks.
It's and old source, but I expected that the documentation explained a little better the trade-off between commits and rollback to savepoint.